# D3.js v5 constructing a tree "matrix"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The goal is to somewhat elegantly append multiple small tree diagrams in the shape of a matrix. I have prepared a simple version of the intended output; the rects and texts show what the pattern is supposed to look like. What needs to happen next is for a simple two-level tree plot to be appended below the rects.

I'm working with a data structure in which the tree data is stored in an object within each item of an array of objects:

```
  var data = [
    {name:"jackie chan", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"}
          ]
    }},
    {name:"jet li", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"},
            { "name": "Fund 4"},
          ]
    }},
...
```

Snippet:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
    {name:"jackie chan", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"}
          ]
    }},
    {name:"jet li", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"},
            { "name": "Fund 4"},
          ]
    }},
    {name:"donnie yen", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
          ]
    }},
    {name:"chow yun fat", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"},
            { "name": "Fund 4"},
            { "name": "Fund 5"},
          ]
    }},
  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 150;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var pmG = graphGroup.selectAll('.pm')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'pm')
    .attr('id', (d, i) => 'pm' + i)
    .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
      var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
      var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
      return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
    });

var miniTree = d3.tree()
    .size([150, 75]);

pmG.append('rect')
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',100)
    .attr('height',25)
    .style('fill',"#003366");

pmG.append('text')
    .attr('x',50)
    .attr('y',-10)
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .text(function(d) {return d.name});

pmG.selectAll(null)
    .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree).descendants().slice(1))})
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
       return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
         + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
         + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
         + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
       });

pmG.selectAll(null)
    .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree).descendants())})
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node" +
        (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I thought I could achieve the desired result by encapsulating all the tree methods into one big data call and then use the same approach for appending rects and texts as seen in the snippet result:

```
pmG.selectAll(null)
    .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree).descendants().slice(1))})
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
       return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
         + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
         + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
         + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
       });
```

However I got the error:

> Uncaught type error: i.eachBefore is not a function

I have never seen that kind of error before, and I fear there is a big problem brewing.

### Question

Based off my matrix framework (see how the rects and text are appended in snippet), how can I append small "mini trees" in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in making the tree:

```
 .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree).descendants().slice(1)) })
```

Should be:

```
 .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1)  })
```

You don't want the descendants of d3.hierarchy but miniTree - missed it the first handful of times I looked at it.

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [
    {name:"jackie chan", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"}
          ]
    }},
    {name:"jet li", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"},
            { "name": "Fund 4"},
          ]
    }},
    {name:"donnie yen", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
          ]
    }},
    {name:"chow yun fat", tree: {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "children": [
            { "name": "Fund 1" },
            { "name": "Fund 2" },
            { "name": "Fund 3"},
            { "name": "Fund 4"},
            { "name": "Fund 5"},
          ]
    }},
  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 150;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var pmG = graphGroup.selectAll('.pm')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'pm')
    .attr('id', (d, i) => 'pm' + i)
    .attr('transform', (d, k) => {
      var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
      var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
      return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
    });

var miniTree = d3.tree()
    .size([150, 75]);

pmG.append('rect')
    .attr('x',0)
    .attr('y',0)
    .attr('width',100)
    .attr('height',25)
    .style('fill',"#003366");

pmG.append('text')
    .attr('x',50)
    .attr('y',-10)
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .text(function(d) {return d.name});


pmG.selectAll(null)
    .data( function(d) { 
        return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1) 
        
        })
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-25,20)") // extra positioning.
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
       return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
         + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
         + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
         + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
       });

pmG.selectAll(null)
    .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants() })
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node" +
        (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.x - 25) + "," + (d.y+20) + ")"; }) // with extra positioning.
      .append("circle")
```

```css
path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
  stroke: #003366;
}

circle {
  r: 5px;
  fill: #003366;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Paths seem to be appended, but it seems the circles are still missing. Probably another oversight of my code, feel free to scrap that section if you know of an easier way to append circles to the nodes.

Comment: I did add a line to append the circles, their radius is in the css, otherwise you were just appending g elements at the end of the snippet.